# jQuery won't send HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header?

Tags: ajax, django, jquery

I have the following page, and checking the request, I can't find the HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH  header? I even tried various hacks such as adding the header manually (per another question here), but to no avail. Anyone have any ideas?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#form").bind("submit", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault()
                $.post("/members/login/", $("#form").serialize(),
                        function(data){
                            alert(data);
                            });
                });
            }); 
    });
</script>

<form id="form" action="" method="post">
    <ul>
       <li><label for="id_email">Email:</label> <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="id_email" /></li>
       <li><label for="id_password">Password:</label> <input type="password" name="password" id="id_password" /></li>
    </ul>
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="" />
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="" />
</form>
```

This shouldn't matter, but I use django and check with `request.is_ajax()`. I verified that the header isn't in the request. This is deployed on localhost.

Comment: Probably not relevant, but you do seem to have a closing too much ? And just tested your code in jsFiddle, and even tough the request fails (of course) the header does indeed have `X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest`. Use the console in your browser to check the header, and you'll probably find it.

Comment: Ironically, it mattered. I had an issue with an extra semicolon as this was a jQuery wrapped function call. The inner part shouldn't have included a semicolon like this $(...;). This caused the form to submit non-ajax with a page load, instead of catching the event. If you post your comment, I will credit you with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a closing too much in your code, try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#form").on("submit", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            $.post("/members/login/", $("#form").serialize(), function(data){
                console.log(data);
            });
         });
    }); 
</script>
```